# Pull info from datapool, increment a value and store the datapool

Tags: rft

The application I test has some areas where it requires unique data.  Specifically, the application will generate a request number that can only be used once.  After my test runs I must manually update my datapool reference for this number.  Is there any way using java, that I can get the information stored in my datapool, increase the value by one, and then save the data back to the datapool.  This way I can keep rft in sync with my application in regard to this number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to read a value from the datapool, increment it by 1, and save it back to the datapool. It is an adapted example from the book [Software Test Engineering with IBM Rational Functional Tester](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/testengineeringrft/index.html?ca=drs). The original source code is from chapter 5 (and can be downloaded from the book's homepage).

```
// some imports
import org.eclipse.hyades.edit.datapool.IDatapoolCell;
import org.eclipse.hyades.edit.datapool.IDatapoolEquivalenceClass;
import org.eclipse.hyades.execution.runtime.datapool.IDatapool;
import org.eclipse.hyades.execution.runtime.datapool.IDatapoolRecord;

int value = dpInt("value");
value++;
java.io.File dpFile = new java.io.File((String) getOption(IOptionName.DATASTORE), "SomeDatapool.rftdp");
IDatapool dp = dpFactory().load(dpFile, true);
IDatapoolEquivalenceClass equivalenceClass = (IDatapoolEquivalenceClass) dp.getEquivalenceClass(dp
        .getDefaultEquivalenceClassIndex());
IDatapoolRecord record = equivalenceClass.getRecord(0);
IDatapoolCell cell = (IDatapoolCell) record.getCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(value);
DatapoolFactory factory = DatapoolFactory.get();
factory.save((org.eclipse.hyades.edit.datapool.IDatapool) dp);
```

I think it is quite a lot of code to simply change one value—maybe it is easier to use some other method like writing the value to a normal text file.